display current git HEAD on footer of website, using github pages and static html website
I am using github.com pages and git. I would like to display the current git HEAD on the footer of my webpage. However, its like a chicken and the egg problem. If I commit, then create a text file with the git HEAD (for later inclusion in the html using a javascript, for instance) then that text file is not committed, and therefore the git HEAD value lags by one version. Is there a solution?

Why do you want to display commit ID? Github Pages display the latest commit you've pushed so anyone can just look the commit up in the source repository.

@phd so that customers, when they send me a screenshot of the page, include the git HEAD, for debugging purposes. I also want the shopping cart to save git HEAD referring to the terms and conditions when a customer makes a purchase.

Then you need 2 commits per push.

@phd But the second commit will change the git HEAD again no? So the git HEAD showing on the footer will lag by one version?

You don't need to show exactly the HEAD, you only need to show commit ID that is close enough. Previous commit ID is a good approximation.

@Anon21 hi! Did you find any solution?

@Daniel I did not.
